# Don't preserve the final state when purging a deleted chat message's history

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

Occasionally, regular deleting isn't good enough, and super-strength internet bleach needs to be applied to chat messages.

The process is this:

1. A user requests a chat message be mod-removed
2. I comply, and delete the message. I then access the message history, and purge it.
3. Too late I remember! Having purged the history, the final state of the message from before it was deleted is preserved, and *uneditable!*
4. Get higher-ups to clean up my mess

Thus, if you want to *remove* remove a message from chat you have to edit it to a placeholder, like "(deleted)", then purge the history. Forget step one, and the opposite of what you want happens: the message is public forever.

Given that this action is usually taken when a user has accidentally posted personally identifying or otherwise sensitive information in chat, this is a pretty bad thing to happen.

What I propose is that purging the history of a *deleted* message should leave the final state of the message as (deleted). The deleted information should not be retained.

Comment: You *can* fake the POST request to edit it after it's been deleted, then purge, but most people don't want to do that.

Comment: @Undo It still doesn't make the post editable after erroneously purging though.

Comment: `$.post('http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/'+id, {text: 'nothing to see here', fkey: fkey().fkey});` It's called *maaaaaagic*.

Comment: I prefer UI buttons to magic.

Answer (score 4):

I have added a button (using pretty much the script posted above by ɥʇǝS) to [Porkchat](https://stackapps.com/questions/6266/porkchat-a-chrome-extension-with-lots-of-chat-tweaks), users of the extension can now edit messages from the history page.

[image]